# How to center an image (graphics, tikzs, and so on) vertically by using paracol?

Tags: minipage, columns, paracol

I want to center the image vertically, not only horizontally (by use `\centering`). How can I do it?

[image]

Just like the image below, I want to make the tikz in the red box, not at the top of the right column.

I tried using minipage, however its very awful.

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  paperwidth=21.590cm, 
  paperheight=28.787cm,
  top=21.2mm, 
  bottom=21.2mm, 
  left=1.91cm, 
  right=1.91cm, 
  headheight=1.81cm, 
  headsep=3.3mm, 
  footskip=4.71mm
}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{paracol}
\columnratio{0.67}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    blanker,breakable,
    borderline west={1.5pt}{3mm}{teal},
    left=6mm,
    toprule=.3em,
    bottomrule=.3em,
    title=Title,
    bottomtitle=.75\baselineskip,
    coltitle=teal,
    fonttitle=\bfseries]
  Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. Here are questions. Right is a tikzpicture. 
\end{tcolorbox}
\switchcolumn
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thick] (0,0) circle (1);
    \draw [thick,densely dotted] (0,-1)--(-3,-1);
    \draw [|<-,thick,>=stealth] (-2.7,-1)--(-2.7,0);
    \draw [->|,thick,>=stealth] (-2.7,0.5)--(-2.7,1.5);
    \node at (-2.7,0.25) {$H$};
    \draw [thick] (-2.5,1.5) arc (-180:-90:2.5);
    \shade[ball color=blue!80!red!50] (-2.4,1.4) circle (0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I use minipage, I should also use command`\noindent`, however the tcolorbox left will 'break'...

Comment: Package `paracol` uses vertical synchronization, i.e. ignores all attempts for vertical alignment. See its manual https://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol-man.pdf . However, the colorful example on p. 44ff (46 in pdf) may or may not be helpful.